# Rave Reports DataText Left

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, rave-reports, datatextfield

I'm using Delphi 7 and Rave Reports. 
How can I set the DataText.Left property (from Rave Reports) dinamicaly according to the size of another DataText that comes before. 
I tried using the width from the previous DataText, the Length of the field that the first DataText is displaying... None of them worked.
I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Length does not take the width of the characters into account, which will vary depending on the font settings.

```
// Assumes the AutoSize property is true.
// Note: 8 is added as spacing
DataText.Left := LastDataText.Left + LastDataText.Width + 8;
```

If your loading the data from a DataSet, have a look at the [DisplayWidth](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TField_DisplayWidth.html) property of the TField class.

```
// calculate the width of the last field.
TextWidth := DataSet.Fields[0].DisplayWidth * QuickReport.Canvas.TextWidth('M');
DataText.Left := LastDataText.Left + TextWidth;
```

Comment: I have not tested the above code.  I need to check the *QuickReport.Canvas* is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, depending on the exact effect you need, you can also use just one datatext, and concatenate data/static text fields like this:

```
<FieldName> + ' Some text ' + <Param.ParamName> + ' Some other text'
```